# Accessing my Windows 7 files from my Ubuntu account

Tags: dual-boot, files, window

I have just installed Ubuntu on my computer and I have windows 7 as my other operating system. is there a way that I can access my windows 7 files from my Ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Just open up Nautilus the file manager by clicking the Home Icon. On the left hand side of Nautilus you should see a drive symbol that will have a name relating to "windows" or the size of the partition such as "125GB filesystem" (where 125GB is the size of your windows partition). Click that to mount your windows partition and access all your files. [A visual guide is located here.](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountwindows)

Comment: I've tried doing this but my partition doesn't seem to show up, is this because I used the windows installer and it is on the same partition?

Comment: @VincePettit With the Windows Installer (Wubi) your Windows partition is available under `/host`

Comment: @bcbc except Wubi is installed in other partition...